# Many Many to many relationships databse design with MySql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am just designing a DB with 4 tables and these tables have a many to many relationship with each other. So it's not just books and authors, but language A, B, C, D .How many intermediary tables will I  need?

16? Or is it just one with 4 columns ?

I am a newbie and quite in despair, because I could not find any info on such a case. Please help.

I see this is not enough info.

There will be 4 languages like
english, germangerman, austriangerman, swissgerman and it should be possible to query from all to all.

So as far as I learned RDBMS , this should be many to many relationships. So the questions is should I create for each pair of tables one intermediary table or would one table with 4 columns be enough?

Comment: You may want to describe your model in greater detail than that.

Comment: *4 tables and these tables have a many to many relationship with each other* I.e. 6 M:N relations? I doubt that this can work.. Maybe you mean the case with only one base table and another tables related as M:N to it (3 relations)? Describe completely and detailed. PS. `language` may be a column with SET datatype.

Comment: Help us to help you by following this link. https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Why not one?

```
author_id ...,
book_id ...,
lang_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci,
dim_4 ??
```

You may need multiple `INDEXes` on this mapping table.  Let's see the likely queries.